# disable lengthNorm (length normalization)

Tags: solr

I would like to disable lengthNorm in Solr. Some people suggest using omitNorms=true. but I can't use it because I also want to do index time boost. "omitNorms=true" seems to disable index time boost. 
another approach I found online is to override lengthNorm method in DefaultSimilarty. but looks like this method is no longer used in Solr 4.0. Is there another other way to do so?

```
public float lengthNorm(String fieldName, int numTerms) {
    return numTerms > 0 ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the source of [DefaultSimilarity](http://fossies.org/dox/apache-solr-4.0.0-src/DefaultSimilarity_8java_source.html) for 4.0

```
@Override
public void computeNorm(FieldInvertState state, Norm norm) {
    final int numTerms;
    if (discountOverlaps)
        numTerms = state.getLength() - state.getNumOverlap();
    else
        numTerms = state.getLength();
    norm.setByte(encodeNormValue(state.getBoost() * ((float) (1.0 / Math.sqrt(numTerms)))));
}
```

You can create a Custom class with numTerms equal to 1 or remove the calculation `((float) (1.0 / Math.sqrt(numTerms)))` to eliminate lengthNorm effect.